# Vue3 / Nuxt3 - how to use props directly in setup

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

Can you please help me fix this error :
Getting a value from the `props` in root scope of `<script setup>` will cause the value to lose reactivity.(vue/no-setup-props-destructure)

I'm using :

- nuxt: "^3.6.5"
- typescript: "^5.1.6"
- eslint: "^8.46.0
- eslint-config-prettier: "^8.10.0"
- eslint-plugin-nuxt: "^4.0.0"
- eslint-plugin-vitest: "^0.2.8"
- eslint-plugin-vue: "^9.16.1"
- eslint-plugin-vuetify: "^2.0.5"

This is a sample code which illustrate the problem :

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
  const props = defineProps<{ fruit: string }>()
  const fruitColor = ref<FruitColor>(getColor(props.fruit))
</script>
```

This is my .eslintrc.js, it may help

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true
  },
  extends: ['@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript', 'plugin:nuxt/recommended', 'plugin:vitest/recommended', 'prettier'],
  rules: {
    'vue/script-indent': ['error', 2, { baseIndent: 1 }],
    'vue/max-len': ['error', { code: 120 }],
    'vue/component-name-in-template-casing': [
      'error',
      'kebab-case',
      {
        registeredComponentsOnly: true,
        ignores: []
      }
    ],
    'comma-dangle': ['error', 'never'],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to go back in order to answer after I found the solution.
It's in the doc  : https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities
`toRef(props.fruit)` or `const {fruit} = toRefs(props)` to transform all.

```
// creates read and write access without modifying original props.fruit
toRef(props.fruit)

// creates a readonly ref that calls the getter on .value access
toRef(() => props.foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a computed property instead of a ref. Computed properties inherently monitors their reactive dependencies, so any changes in `props.fruit` will effectively trigger reactivity.

**Code Changes:**

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
  const props = defineProps<{ fruit: string }>()
  const fruitColor = computed<FruitColor>(() => getColor(props.fruit));  
</script>
```